# node_modules - Zipproto.ts and mergeproto.ts files are not found

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015, npm-install, node-modules

I am working on sample application using angular 2 in visual studio 2015. I have copied the quick start configuration files package.json, tsconfig.json.
Now after installing npm package dependencies, I am getting following error after building the application. Please find the screenshot.

[image: Files not found in node_modules]

Why the files are not included after installing the packages in node_modules folder?

Can anyone help me in resolving the error?

Comment: Have you resolved this issue?

Comment: Hi @Mergasov , I am not sure what is the root cause of the issue but you can do a workaround to fix the issue by excluding the "node_modules" folder i.e let the node_modules be a hidden folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check if a `tsconfig.json` exists in your app root folder. if it does take out or delete the other `tsconfig.json` found in the `node_modules\browser-sync\node_modules\rx\ts`. This should solve the problem.