# Visual Studio 2017 dotnet core angular 2 app wont build because of two files

Tags: angular, npm, visual-studio-2017

Recently I have been having some trouble getting my angular 2 app going in Visual Studio 2017. I keep getting an error saying I am missing two files.

One is named mergeproto.ts and the other is named zipproto.ts. Both of these files are under the browser-sync module.

I was able to find some other posts pertaining to this issue, but all of them are from last year, and none of the solutions in these posts appear to be working for me.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/1247

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/10702

[node_modules - Zipproto.ts and mergeproto.ts files are not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40864150/node-modules-zipproto-ts-and-mergeproto-ts-files-are-not-found)

Has anyone else experienced this issue and found a way to get around it?

Comment: Try deleting node_modules folder and run npm install

Comment: Yeah I tried that. Still getting an error that the two files are missing.

Both files are from the browser-sync package.